# magento : product image is not uploading in admin panel while creating product

Tags: php, image, magento-1.9, image-uploading, product

I have checked

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/editor.phtml
```

these are present
also
Given full permission to Media folder
php.ini max upload value set to 128M 
[image: While uploading after selecting the image when click on upload then its turns red as shown below with the image name]

Answer (score 0):

When was it last working, have you checked it? Because this happens due to many reason. I would recommend to uninstall extensions which you have installed after which your image upload stop working.

Check your error.log and system.log for more information.

Comment: this problem occurs on a new installation. I have tried two times. After installing both time it happens in localhost.